# Not able to add the libraries in the Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, libraries, pythoninterpreter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<frozen runpy\>", line 198, in \_run_module_as_main
File "\<frozen runpy\>", line 88, in _run_code
File "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.4\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl\\pip_main_.py", line 23, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.4\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl\\pip_internal\\cli\\main.py", line 10, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.4\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl\\pip_internal\\cli\\autocompletion.py", line 9, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.4\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl\\pip_internal\\cli\\main_parser.py", line 7, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.4\\plugins\\python-ce\\helpers\\pip-20.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl\\pip_internal\\cli\\cmdoptions.py", line 18, in \<module\>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

I have tried updating the pip version and updating the python version

Comment: It worked after installing the setup tools

Answer (score 1):

The Pip 20.3.4 helper wheel bundled with your 2022.1 version of PyCharm is not compatible with your version of Python (since distutils is missing, I'd guess 3.12).

Trying to update your `pip` by hand won't help because this is the bundled `pip`.

Update your PyCharm version instead, or downgrade to a Python version supported by it (Python 3.10 had been released at the time of PyCharm 2022.1 being released).

You can also try to install `setuptools` (which is the library that provides `distutils` for Python 3.12), but I would recommend updating PyCharm.

Comment: I'm not sure this is accurate since when creating a venv in PyCharm you choose a base Python installation from which the venv will be created. Hence, unless I'm mistaken whatever pip version gets installed by running `python -m venv` is independent from the PyCharm version and depends only on the base interpreter. Here the OP doesn't specify what they are doing, what does it mean *"to add the libraries in the Pycharm"* we don't know because the OP doesn't say where and how he is adding them. My guess is they're starting from a venv without pip, which is peculiar to conda not venv nor PyCharm.

Comment: Another issue is under what circumstances does PyCharm call its internal pip instead of the project's pip or the base interpreter's pip? Again, that would happen under the narrow circumstance of having a venv without pip and without any other reachable Python on the path where pip could be found. So, I think the question doesn't provide enough of a minimum reproducible example to actually be useful because this description would have to be included (otherwise future readers are left to deduce all of this as I just did - and that seems like an unreasonable expectation).

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate @AKX for your reply, I have debugged where I am getting stuck. It is with my setup tools not installed. After installing the setup tools everything working.